# How to make Point InTime API request of Elasticsearch using JAVA High Level REST client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

It will be helpful if someone can point me to a way to execute Point In Time API request, which is newly introduced in Elasticsearch 7.10.1, from JAVA using REST high-level client or any other way in JAVA. (except Transport client as it is going to be deprecated soon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Low level rest client comes to rescue when high level rest client doesn't have a wrapper for any api. You can use low level client via high level client as below:

```
String endPoint = "my-index-000001/_pit";
Request request = new Request("POST", endPoint);
request.addParameter("keep_alive", "1m");
Response response = highLevelClient.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
```

Then use the `response` object to extract out the relevant information.

Comment: Thank you. So till now there is no direct way to make PIT request using REST high level client . We have to use low level client only. I wanted to make sure that if the elastic documentation is missing it or it has not been introduced as part of REST high level client at all.