# How to create point in time reference elasticsearch using java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I would like to use the [elastic search high level client](https://web.archive.org/web/20210623172836/https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html) to execute this simple POST:

```
POST /my-index-000001/_pit?keep_alive=1m
```

Reading the documentation I am getting quite confused. For instance, using the [IndexAPI](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-index.html) seems a good fit, but I am not sure it is the correct path .

Can anyone show me an example?

Comment: actually, not really convinced that IndexAPI is the way to go. Might be blind, but I cannot see anything to make a simple post to that endpoint..

Comment: Just found the answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699492/how-to-make-point-intime-api-request-of-elasticsearch-using-java-high-level-rest

Answer (score 2):

Here the working solution for me:

```
     String endPoint = "/index-name/_pit";
        Request request = new Request("POST", endPoint);
        request.addParameter("keep_alive", "10m");
     client.getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
```

Please note the forward slash before the index-name, otherwise you will get a bad request.

Answer (score 0):

For any one using [java-client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html) either [ElasticsearchClient](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.0.1/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchClient.html) or [ElasticsearchAsyncClient](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.1.0/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAsyncClient.html)

you can use `openPointInTime` methods

**ElasticsearchAsyncClient**

```
CompletableFuture<OpenPointInTimeResponse>  openPointInTime​(OpenPointInTimeRequest request)
```

**ElasticsearchClient**

```
OpenPointInTimeResponse openPointInTime​(OpenPointInTimeRequest request)
```

You can create `OpenPointInTimeRequest` for index or index patterns by passing time

```
 OpenPointInTimeRequest request = new OpenPointInTimeRequest.Builder()
     .index("index-1")
     .time(new Time.Builder().time("1m").build())
     .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String createOpenPointInTimeRequest(String indexName) throws IOException {
    OpenPointInTimeRequest request = new OpenPointInTimeRequest.Builder()
            .index(indexName)
            .keepAlive(new Time.Builder().time("3m").build())
            .build();


    OpenPointInTimeResponse openPointInTimeResponse = elasticsearchClient.openPointInTime(request);

    return openPointInTimeResponse.id();
}
```

My elastic client is 8.3.3